# updating session

Tags: php, session, authentication

I use session to remember username and password for my members. 
No I have added a function which detects the portview as below. 
I think it is in conflict 'cos for a logged in user the portview is not set. 
Can anyone help me?

```
    session_start();
$_SESSION['viewportheight'] = $_POST['height'];
$_SESSION['viewportwidth'] = $_POST['width'];
```

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: Also,  is it really necessary to store the user's password in a session variable? Why? It's often an unnecessary security risk.

Comment: Consider adding them as cookies instead of session... You can set different set of viewport for different users too..

Comment: Does $_POST contain width and height keys when you're calling the function that sets the session viewport values ? , allso if you allready started the session ( ie. you can retrive the username/password from $_SESSION ) you don't need to call session_start() again

Comment: Don't listen to kvijayhari, storing the password in cookie would be a billion times worse than storing it in session. Can't you just store a login status? Not the password? You shouldn't even store the password in a database. You should store a 1 way hash of it.

Comment: @DampeS8N: storing width & height in cookies would be the RESTful approach (my reading of kvijayhari's comment is that he's referring to the problematic width & height session data, not the password). You're spot on about passwords, however. Just don't forget to the salt.

Comment: Salt it, add on the username, and hash that SOB with SHA256 or 512 and you'll never have to worry about password security again.

Comment: @DampeS8N: I'm not saying about storing username and passwords mate.. He told he stored them in session already so i told to store the viewport in cookies.. Is there any harm to that????

Answer (score 0):

What is the conflict here?

By the way, you can use the isset() method to check if the variables $_POST['height'] and $_POST['width'] are set and assign them to the session variables only if they are set.